# Entity Framework code-first IQueryable navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, iqueryable

Most of the examples I see on the internet show the navigation properties as either `ICollection` or straight `List` implementation. They are usually `virtual`, to enable lazy-loading.

However, when you access such property, it will load the entire collection in memory and if you have a subquery after it (i.e. `object.MyListProperty.Where(...)`) I have noticed that an SQL query will be issued for each item in the `MyListProperty`.

How do I avoid this? I want the `where` clause after the list property to execute on the SQL server, if possible. Can I use an `IQueryable` navigation property? Is there any best-practice for such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: Navigation Properties Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357511/entity-framework-navigation-properties-issue)

Comment: I see your point, but no, `IQueryable<T>` is not a valid nagivation property type. Even `IEnumerable<T>` is not. `ICollection<T>` is a minimum, and derived from it of course.

Answer (score 1):

My advice for *best practise* is to *disable* Lazy loading altogether. Instead force the caller to *eagerly* load navigation properties through include statements or by using projections.

> There are 3rd party products that support include with filters, as described in this post: [How to filter include entities in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework), but in my experience this further complicates down-stream processing of the objects that are retrieved. If the entity object is loaded outside of method `X`, because method `X` can't know for sure if the navigation properties have been loaded with the correct filters, method `X` starts off by re-querying for the precise rows that it knows it needs.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    // TODO: load your data
    ...
}
```

In this way the records will only be loaded when they are explicitly requested.

When you want access to an `IQueryable` so you can defer the loading of the data, then make those queries against the DbContext *instance* and not from the object.

- In this example assume that a `Customer` has many thousands of transactions, so we don't want them to be *eagerly* or *lazy* loaded at all.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var customer = context.Customers.First(x => x.Id == 123);
    ...
    // count the transactions in the last 30 days for this customer
    int customerId = customer.Id;  
    DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30)

    // different variations on the same query
    int transactionCount1 = context.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == customerId)
                                             .SelectMany(x => x.Transactions.Where(x => x.TransactionDate >= dateFrom))
                                             .Count();
    int transactionCount2 = context.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == customerId)
                                             .SelectMany(x => x.Transactions)
                                             .Where(x => x.TransactionDate >= dateFrom)
                                             .Count();
    int transactionCount3 = context.Transactions.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId)
                                                .Where(x => x.TransactionDate >= dateFrom)
                                                .Count();
}
```

It is good that you have identified that you want to use an `IQueryable<T>` we access them from the `DbContext` directly, not from the instances that were previously retrieved.